# How to prove that 2 disjoint subsets in a metric space can be subsets of each other's boundaries?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

The question is as follows:

Does there exist a metric space ($X$, $d_X$) and two subsets, $A\subset X, B \subset X$ such that $A \cap B =  \emptyset $ and $A\subset \partial B $ and $B \subset \partial A$? If such metric space exists, give an explicit example of X, A, and B. If not, prove this metric space doesn't exist.

I believe the $\partial$ symbol means boundary of the set? Can someone show me how to solve this or at least start the proof?

Comment: Consider $A=\mathbb{Q}.$ Can you think of $B$ and $X$?

Comment: Try $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^c$ or $\mathbb{Q}+\{ \sqrt{2}\}$.